# How to display the data of the parent table using the data in the child table in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, notifications

I am trying to make a web application in C # Asp.net mcv 4.

I'm at the level where I would have to show data of a table "Notifications" based on the data in a table "ReadNotifs".

To illustrate the problem, here are more details:

I have two tables in my database: Notifications and ReadNotifs.

```
Table : Notifications            Table : ReadNotifs
--------------------------      --------------------------
|NotificationID | int    |      |ReadNotifID    | int    |
|description    | string |      |userid         | int    |
|UserId         | int    |      |NotificationID | int    |
__________________________      __________________________
```

- These are the related models :

  ```
   public class Notification
   {
      public Notification()
      {
          this.ReplyNotifs = new HashSet<ReplyNotif>();
      }

      [Key]
      public int NotificationID { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Comment")]
      public string description { get; set; }

      public int UserId { get; set; }
      public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<ReadNotif> ReadNotifs { get; set; }
  }

  public class ReadNotif
  {
      [Key]
      public int ReadNotifID { get; set; }

      public int userid { get; set; }

      public int NotificationID { get; set; }
      public virtual Notification Notification { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Notifications and ReadNotifs tables are linked by the relationship One to many. So 1 Notification can be read (ReadNotif) several times.

I wish I could have this result :

```
Table : Notifications               Table : ReadNotifs
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
|NotificationID|description|UserId| |ReadNotifID|userid|NotificationID|
|      1       | Post 1    |  50  | |     1     |  50  |      3       |
|      2       | Post 2    |  51  | |     2     |  50  |      1       |
|      3       | Post 3    |  52  | ___________________________________
|      4       | Post 4    |  53  | 
___________________________________ 

Result that i want to display in my view:

Table : Notifications              
----------------------------------- 
|NotificationID|description|UserId|  
|      2       | Post 2    |  51  |
|      4       | Post 4    |  53  | 
___________________________________
```

Remember : I would have to show data in a table "Notifications" based on the data in a table "ReadNotifs". 
So, i want to display a Notification when NotificationID(of Notifications) != NotificationID (ReadNotifs).

Any idea how I should proceed?

Thank you very much.

EDIT : Hi all. i tried something :

My ViewModel :

```
public class NotificationVM
{
    public ReadNotif ReadNotif { get; set; }
    public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller :

```
UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name); 

var listreadnotifs = db.ReadNotifs
                                 //.Where(u => u.userid == user.UserId)
                                     .ToList();

                if (listreadnotifs != null)
                {
                    List<NotificationVM> result = new List<NotificationVM>();

                    foreach (var item in listreadnotifs)
                    {
                        NotificationVM model = new NotificationVM();
                        //model.ReadNotif = item;
                        model.Notifications = db.Notifications
                            .OrderByDescending(i => i.NotificationID)
                            .Where(u => !(u.NotificationID == item.NotificationID))
                            .Take(99)
                            .ToList();

                        result.Add(model);

                    }
                    return PartialView(result);
                }
```

My View :

```
 @foreach (var beta in Model)
    {
        foreach (var item in beta.Notifications)
        {
            @item.description
        }
    }
```

When i apply this method, let me show you the result with the last exemple :

```
Table : Notifications               Table : ReadNotifs
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
|NotificationID|description|UserId| |ReadNotifID|userid|NotificationID|
|      1       | Post 1    |  50  | |     1     |  50  |      3       |
|      2       | Post 2    |  51  | |     2     |  50  |      1       |
|      3       | Post 3    |  52  | ___________________________________
|      4       | Post 4    |  53  | 
___________________________________ 

Result :

(i have this result)                    (instead of this one)
Table : Notifications                   Table : Notifications
-----------------------------------     -----------------------------------
|NotificationID|description|UserId|     |NotificationID|description|UserId|
|      1       | Post 1    |  50  |     |      2       | Post 2    |  51  |
|      2       | Post 2    |  51  |     |      4       | Post 4    |  53  |
|      4       | Post 4    |  53  |     ___________________________________
___________________________________
```

So this solution work partially.

Any idea ?

Ty

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to display all records from `Notifications` except those that have a corresponding record in `ReadNotifs` (i.e. unread notifications)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, one idear ?

Comment: Something like `var result = notifications.Where(n => !readNotifs.Any(r => r.NotificationID == n.NotificationID));`

Comment: Oh Thank you Sir Stephen Muecke. That's work like i want :) i will edit the first post with right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a collection of all `Notifications` except those that have a corresponding record in ReadNotifs (i.e. unread notifications), you can use the following query

```
List<Notification> unreadNotifications = db.Notifications
  .Where(n => !db.ReadNotifs.Any(r => r.NotificationID == n.NotificationID));
```

Side note: Its not really clear what the purpose of the `ReadNotif` property is in your view model is (you never set it anywhere) so it seems unnecessary. You could just make the model in the view `@model List<Notification>`

Answer (score 0):

As I see from you code, the best approach for that is using "include" in your controller method, something like this:

```
var notifs = db.ReadNotifs.Include(a => a.Notifications);
        return View(notifs);
```

Comment: Hi, it's didn't work. look : https://gyazo.com/3490c66f3be0aa207c06f7247aa92cc1   . Please see my post again, i will edit my post to show what i'm trying. Ty

Comment: That was an example to show you how to use "include". Check your objects relations to change that example to suit to your code.

Comment: or may be you need change the code to : var notifs = db.Notifications.Include(a => a.ReadNotifs);

Comment: Yes Sir, i tried, it's didn't work. Please see my firt post, i Edited my post, i show how i tried another code, but didn't work also (work partially). Ty for your help.

Comment: check "u => u.userid == user.UserId". probably you filter based on userid=52 , that is why you get result for userid=50

Comment: I removed this code ("u => u.userid == user.UserId"), but i have the same problem it work partially again

Comment: delete "Take(99) and .ToList();" and tell me the resualts. after that may be need adding some code based on resualt

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir Hadee. Sir Stephen Muecke posted the right code. Thank you very much for your help. i will edit the first post with right code.